# Simple razor templating syntax to include a comma to separate the names

Tags: c#, .net, html, razor

I have the following razor template html, although I can't figure out how to include a comma to separate the names within the markup!?  When trying the following code I get `; expected` as a compiler error!.  I'll also need to remove the last comma as well.

```
@foreach (People person in Model.People)
{
  person.Name,
}
```

I want: Ted, James, Jenny, Tom

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What about [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) instead of `foreach` (it even solves the comma after the last item  problem):

```
@String.Join(", ", Model.People.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray())
```

Comment: +1, and in addition, though it can get a bit messy, you can also extend this to use ActionLinks: `@Html.Raw(String.Join(", ", Model.People.Select(p => Html.ActionLink(p.Name, "Details").ToHtmlString()).ToArray()))`

Comment: 4 years later and LINQ still amazes me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to `Html.Encode` the `p.Name`? Also, was `ToArray` ever needed?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `<text></text>` to include literal content in a Razor template. To omit the last comma, I would use a `for` loop rather than `foreach`.

```
@{
    var peopleList = Model.People.ToList();

    for( int i = 0; i < peopleList.Count; i++ )
    {
        @peopleList[i].Name
        if( i < peopleList[i].Count - 1 )
        {
            <text>,</text>
        }
    }
}
```

As @nemesv points out, if all you are doing is creating and displaying a delimited string, `string.Join()` is a cleaner way to accomplish this. If you are building more complex markup, you will probably need to use a loop.

Comment: Just a side question, but wouldn't this invoke the Count() method/extension with every loop twice?

Comment: Yes. If you had 5 names, then it's no big deal. If you had 5000 names, then by all means evaluate count once and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve the result in a compact way using ternary operator

```
@foreach (People person in Model.People)
{
  @person.Name@((person != Model.People.Last()) ? "," : "")
}
```

Comment: This going to have a bad runtime performance if your `People` collection is large. Especially so if `Model.People` is a live EF database entity set object.

Answer (score 2):

An idea for a scenario where you need to do additional "stuff" in the foreach loop than just rendering the display.

```
// index.cshtml
@{ var lastPerson = Model.People.LastOrDefault(); }
@foreach (People person in Model.People)
{
    var display = person != lastPerson ? $"{person.Name}, " : person.Name;
    <a href="@person.Href">@display</a>
}
```

Or if you're like me and you want to try to keep comparison and parsing logic out of the view, you can write a simple extension method.

```
// StringExtensions.cs
public class StringExtensions
{
    public static string DisplayAsCommaListItem(
        this string str, object currentItem, object lastItem)
    {
        return currentItem != lastItem ? $"{str}, " : str;
    }
}
```

Then the view code becomes..

```
// index.cshtml
@{ var lastPerson = Model.People.LastOrDefault(); }
@foreach (People person in Model.People)
{
    <a href="@person.Href">@person.Name.DisplayAsCommaListItem(person, lastPerson)</a>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (People person in Model.People)
{
  person.Name<text>,&nbsp;</text>
}
```

or better:

```
string.Join(", ", Model.People.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool firstIteration = true

@foreach (People person in Model.People)
{

if(firstIteration)

{

  @: person.Name

}

else

{

 @: "," + person.Name

}

firstIteration = false;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
@foreach (People person in Model.People)
{
  @person.Name<text>,</text>
}
```

Comment: This would result in `Ted,James,Jenny,Tom,` and not `Ted, James, Jenny, Tom`